# Gradle sync failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 522 for URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I am trying to use my android project on another pc. I transferred the project folder to the new pc but when I try to open it in Android Studio gradle project refresh fails and I get this error. I tried restarting Studio and invading caches but in vain.Please guide me, thanks in advance !!

```
Error:Server returned HTTP response code: 522 for URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP response code [522](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#522) means that the connection timed out on the server that you are trying to download gradle from. The server may have been very busy or had some other problem when you requested the zip. I've just tried the url and successfully downloaded the zip (although it did take longer than I'd expect). So my advice is to try again.